Girl able to predict future events, people able to read mind?
I'm trying to know the name of this movie I saw before. The movie about a girl (short, more like an emo kid), with a diary where she draws images that depicts future events. People are trying to chase her, there is the hero where he create elaborate plans to evade the crisis or something. Some people in the movie were able to read minds, block other people from reading minds, erase minds etc. Do you know the name of the movie?  Thanks.

It must be Push. Cassie Holmes (played by Dakota Fanning) is the emo kid you are referring too. She is a watcher. Main hero is a mover(can move things without touching) . He plans with his group how to change their fate. Because the emo Girl with vision predicted that they are going to die. One man with black nails can erase memories, hero and his group use him to distract rival watcher by removing their own memory for a short while. Blocking user from reading mind...not sure about it.
